# Win 8 UAC : how to give any specific app admin rights from user account.

Tags: administrator

I need to give admin rights to specific application in user account. I have tried task scheduler trick but no luck..

Can anybody help me if you understand my problem.

Comment: right click - run as admin?

Comment: You can only do this if one of two things happens.  The user itself is an `Administrator` or they escalate the permissions of the process by authenticating as an `Administrator` ( i.e. "run as administrator" ).

Comment: i have used the following command & it works as charm....                         Create shortcut & use this command
Runas /user:<domain>\administrator /savered “c:\test.test.exe”